# Using Stack Exchange big data for analysis

Tags: support, licensing

I downloaded large data sets of Stack Exchange from this:
https://archive.org/download/stackexchange

I'm going to use those data for some analysis & going to open source those analysis data.

Do I have to ask for special permission from Stack Exchange to use those data? Or else can I use them without any problem?

Comment: Did you read through SE's legal page to see the terms applied to content on the site?  That's the place to start.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go though the page. But the question I'm having is I'll not publish copyright data & only using them for analysis, then publish the results of the analysis

Comment: And that's where you go to find the answer to that question.

Comment: Related: *[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677)*